# how to add text and textsize as selected size from spinner on canvas android?

Tags: arraylist, android-edittext, android-canvas, android-spinner, text-size

i set text and textsize from edittextbox i get perfect size as i selected but whenever i set different textsize for another text it takes same textsize for both text as second textsize...i want text as selected textsize form spinner...help...

Thank u in advance

here is my code of alertdialogbox and spinner `

```
  LayoutInflater linf = LayoutInflater.from(c_new);
                    final View inflator = linf.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(c_new);

                    alert.setTitle("EditText");
                    alert.setView(inflator);

                    final EditText editText = (EditText) inflator.findViewById(R.id.editTextResult);

                    alert.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
                        {
                            srt=editText.getText().toString();
                            c.setEdittext(srt);

                            click_values c1 = new click_values();
                            c1.setImage(3);

                            dialog.cancel();



                        }
                    });

                    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

                    alert.show();


                    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner)inflator.findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);

                    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,textSize);

                    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);



                    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                            String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                            c.setTextsize(Float.parseFloat(item));

                            spinner.setPrompt("Select Text Size");

                            // Showing selected spinner item
                            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected Text Size: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                            spinner.setPrompt("Title");

                        }
                    });
```

here is the code for set and get edittext and textsize`

```
  static String Edittext;

public static String getEdittext() {

    return Edittext;

}

public static String setEdittext(String edittext) {
    click_values.Edittext = edittext;
    Edittext = edittext;
    return edittext;
}

static float textsize;

public static float getTextsize() {
    return textsize;
}

public static void setTextsize(float textsize) {
    click_values.textsize = textsize;
}
```

here i how i store text and textsize `

```
ArrayList<EdtText> editTexts = new ArrayList<EdtText>();
ArrayList<Integer> textsize = new ArrayList<Integer>();



    if (text_c == 0 && c.getImage() == 4) {

        mPaint.setTextSize(c.getTextsize());
        mPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        canvas.drawText(c.getEdittext(), startX, startY, mPaint);
        c.setImage(0);


    } else if (c.getImage() == 4) {
        editTexts.add(new EdtText(c.getEdittext(), startX, startY));

        mPaint.setTextSize(c.getTextsize());
        mPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        canvas.drawText(c.getEdittext(), startX, startY, mPaint);

        c.setImage(0);
        text_c = 0;
    }


    for (EdtText l : editTexts) {

        canvas.drawText(l.EdtText1, l.startX, l.stopY, mPaint);

    }
}
```